# How can I use the IntelliProtector API in a win32 DLL program

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm a beginner when it comes to DLLs. I've developed software that I'm trying to protect with [the IntelliProtector API](http://www.intelliprotector.com/Public/Information/Samples/IntelliprotectorSamples.aspx).

My question is this: How can I include such a library/source code (whatever you call it) into my software and have it compiled? I've added the files to my project, it then had some errors related to MFC dll. I Googled and changed settings to shared MFC dll.

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
```

Once I changed that, I now get this error:

```
fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Which I believe is caused by 2 entry points? I can't really figure this one out; any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
1>mfcs100d.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in dllmain.obj
1>E:\software\PokerLog\Debug\Poker.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: Don't make us guess at the error message.

Comment: what do you mean? those errors I've pasted are what I get. My dll uses some windows.h includes while intelliprotector uses stdafx if that helps

Comment: *What* identifiers are multiply defined?  How do they relate to your code?

Comment: ok, sorry, i've just edited with proper error paste, sorry about that

Comment: Read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148791

Comment: I'm really getting confused now, that link explain how to add codes to MFC dllmain. My project dll doesn't use mfc itself (as far as I know). Is my DllMain mandatory to do dll injection? or i should investigate with that initInstance stuff? Really don't know what i'm doing anymore here

Comment: Would it possible to rename my dllmain function to something else and call this new entry point from the dll injector to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If dllmain is your code and you do not need to handle DLL_THREAD_ATTACH and DLL_THREAD_DETACH, then you might want to get rid of your DllMain and move your code to InitInstance/ExitInstance of your CWinApp derived class. Alternatively you might try to play with the linker option /FORCE:MULTIPLE.